# Hibernate is eagerly fetching OneToOne entities when FetchType.LAZY

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Issue: I've written custom query to fetch data from `device_info` table, and made `fetch=FetchType.LAZY`, but then Hibernate is separately querying `device_info` table

Logs

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM devices d LEFT JOIN device_info di ON d.id = di.device_id WHERE d.is_active = TRUE ORDER BY d.created_at DESC, d.created_at desc limit ?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: select deviceinfo0_.`id` as id1_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`created_at` as created_2_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_id` as device_16_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`device_status` as device_s3_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`environment` as environm4_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`firmware_version` as firmware5_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`installation_id` as installa6_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_deleted` as is_delet7_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`is_internal` as is_inter8_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`jira_ticket_number` as jira_tic9_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`os_version` as os_vers10_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`pcb_version` as pcb_ver11_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`progress_status` as progres12_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`updated_at` as updated13_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`upgrade_reason` as upgrade14_5_0_, deviceinfo0_.`workflow_status` as workflo15_5_0_ from `device_info` deviceinfo0_ where deviceinfo0_.`device_id`=?
Hibernate: SELECT COUNT(d.serial_number) FROM devices d LEFT JOIN device_info di ON d.id = di.device_id WHERE d.is_active = TRUE
```

---

Model

`Devices.java`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "devices")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Devices implements Serializable {
    ..
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;
    ..
}
```

`DeviceInfo.java`

```
..
@Entity
@Table(name = "device_info")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class DeviceInfo {
    ..
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "device_id", referencedColumnName = "id", unique = true)
    private Devices device;
    ..
}
```

Repository
`DevicesRepository.java`

```
@Repository
public interface DevicesRepository extends JpaRepository<Devices, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Devices> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM devices d LEFT JOIN device_info di ON d.id = di.device_id WHERE d.is_active = TRUE ORDER BY d.created_at DESC",
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(d.serial_number) FROM devices d LEFT JOIN device_info di ON d.id = di.device_id WHERE d.is_active = TRUE", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Devices> getDevicesV2(Pageable pageable);

}
```

ServiceImplementation
`DevicesServiceImpl.java`

```
@Service("deviceServiceImplV1")
public class DevicesServiceImpl implements DevicesService {
    public Page<Devices> getDevicesV2(Devices device, Map<String, Object> requestParams, Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Devices> deviceList;
        try {
            deviceList = devicesRepository
                    .getDevicesV2(pageable);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new SQLQueryException(filter.getApp(), ex);
        }
        return deviceList;
    }
}
```

---

### Update:

I tried `optional = false` and `@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` but not working

```
public class Devices implements Serializable {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "device", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
```

Comment: Stop using `@Data` as that will create `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods which will trigger eager loading. More detailed explanation see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/

Comment: Wrong written queries may trigger the eager load as well. Try to load an entity using default methods by id and see if it is still loaded eagerly. Also, avoid the native queries as it breaks the HQL features and the cross rdbms compatibility